# how to insert a new field in a json file

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file like this,

```
{
    "AAL": {
        "id": "32313",
        "airport_name": "Aalborg",
        "latitude": "57.1",
        "longitude": "9.85",
        "timezone": "2",
        "dst_indicator": "E",
        "city": "Aalborg",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK",
        "region": "TC1",
        "listing_display": "true",
        "pseudonyms": ""
    },
    "AAR": {
        "id": "32314",
        "airport_name": "Tirstrup",
        "latitude": "56.15",
        "longitude": "10.2167",
        "timezone": "2",
        "dst_indicator": "E",
        "city": "Aarhus",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK",
        "region": "TC1",
        "listing_display": "true",
        "pseudonyms": ""
    }
}
```

I need to add a new field to it and get the result like this, using php. Any help will be appreciated.

```
{
    "AAL": {
        "station_code":"AAL",
        "id": "32313",
        "airport_name": "Aalborg",
        "latitude": "57.1",
        "longitude": "9.85",
        "timezone": "2",
        "dst_indicator": "E",
        "city": "Aalborg",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK",
        "region": "TC1",
        "listing_display": "true",
        "pseudonyms": ""
    },
    "AAR": {
        "station_code":"AAR",
        "id": "32314",
        "airport_name": "Tirstrup",
        "latitude": "56.15",
        "longitude": "10.2167",
        "timezone": "2",
        "dst_indicator": "E",
        "city": "Aarhus",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK",
        "region": "TC1",
        "listing_display": "true",
        "pseudonyms": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve output this way..

```
$data= '{
    "AAL": {
        "id": "32313",
        "airport_name": "Aalborg",
        "latitude": "57.1",
        "longitude": "9.85",
        "timezone": "2",
        "dst_indicator": "E",
        "city": "Aalborg",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK",
        "region": "TC1",
        "listing_display": "true",
        "pseudonyms": ""
    },
    "AAR": {
        "id": "32314",
        "airport_name": "Tirstrup",
        "latitude": "56.15",
        "longitude": "10.2167",
        "timezone": "2",
        "dst_indicator": "E",
        "city": "Aarhus",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK",
        "region": "TC1",
        "listing_display": "true",
        "pseudonyms": ""
    }
}';

$arrData  =  json_decode($data,true);
foreach($arrData as $key=>$val){
    $arrData[$key]['station_code']=$key;
}

echo json_encode($arrData);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the json to a php variable. Here you add the extra field and parse it back to json.

[Check out the php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

### **JSON PARSING IN PHP**

To read a file containing JSON data :

```
$json_array_assc = json_decode(file_get_contents($file_name), true);
```

To add fields to array you can do :

```
$json_array_assc["NEWDATA"]=array('newdata1'=>'foo1','newdata2'=>'foo2');
```

To write the new data to file use :

```
file_put_contents($file_name, json_encode($json_array_assc));
```

Or simply print the array on console window :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json_array_assc);
```

OR

```
echo json_encode($json_array_assc);
```